# Q: Azure AD B2C: SAML IDP initiated to OpenIdConnect, is it possible?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Trying to setup a custom policy in my Azure AD B2C tenant, I need to communicate to an external IDP using SAML IDP initiated, so client can navigate to their dashboard and click to "my app" that goes against my B2C tenant, and authenticates the user and gets send to my application using OpenIdConnect, it is required to me to get it integrated using SAML between my client's dahsboard and my B2C tenant

I used this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-salesforce-saml?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy) as based to create my custom policy using SAML. As SP initiated (through my app in azure ad b2c) works, but now I need to get it working using IDP initiated.
Also found this [idp-initiated](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp/blob/master/policy/SAML-Idp-Initiated/SignUpOrSignInSAML-IdP-Initiated.xml) sample, but here I got 2 problems:

1. This is setting up "my app" as SAML application (protocol in my RelyingParty, not what I want)
2. If I change that one to use "OpenIdConnect" which is desired in my RelyingParty I get the following error in my logs:

> Policy '< myPolicyName >' in tenant '< myTenant >' does not have a
> supported relying party protocol"

So wondering in this point, is this something that's supported? I also got this [unsupported-saml-modalities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy#supported-and-unsupported-saml-modalities) from the documentation and the last bullet point says:

> Identity provider-initiated sign-on, where the identity provider is Azure AD B2C.

So, not really sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is something valid, any help?

Comment: I found later this article: in case someone gets to need it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#identity-provider-initiated-flow



> We don't currently support scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, for example AD-FS, or Salesforce. It is only supported for Azure AD B2C local account authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible, an Idp initiated flow cannot respond to an OIDC relying party, only a SAML relying party.

Secondly, as the doc states, the IdP must be B2C, and will not work for an external IdP federated to B2C.